# QSpinBox fix up down buttons

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtstylesheets, qspinbox

I need to fix the arrows on my spin boxes, while also rounding the spinboxes. Please note that I am using QT designer, and pyqt5 (and importing, not using pyuic5)

Default spinbox "look"

[image]

look" with below stylesheet

[image]

```
background-color: white;
border-style: outset;
border-width: 1px;
border-radius: 6px;
border-color: black
```

Photoshopped image of what I want it to look like

[image]

Note that my main goal is to make it so that the button background doesn't blend in with the number background, since it is kinda hard to see the arrows alone. If your solution is slightly different than image 3 that is fine, as long as the button background stands out more!

Also note that solutions that can be done in pyqt5 designer alone (without pyqt5 code) are preferred, but if necessary pyqt5 code is fine too.

Comment: what is the output of `print(app.style().metaObject().className())`

Comment: "QWindowsVistaStyle" -- What does this mean? I don't think anyone who ever uses my app will use anything before windows 10.

Comment: mmm I do not understand you. The style of the application is managed by QStyle, so if you want to modify any visual characteristic then knowing the current style is essential. For example you will see that the visual aspect changes if you use: `app.setStyle("fusion")`

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know about app styles, I just used the default. Playing around with styles is super useful. Just wondering, is there a way to change them within qt designer? Thanks again!

Comment: Wait, I still have a similar problem. When I apply a border to the spinbox, it messes with the arrow buttons. How do I fix that?

Comment: 1) Click on the "Preview in" option from the "View" menu. 2) I never said that it is the solution, I just pointed it out to illustrate the question of styles in Qt.

Comment: K thanks! Any advice to fix my problem (as seen in images)?